# get non-type template parameters into tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

How does one construct a tuple with non type template parameters

```
template <auto... args>
void func()
{
  std::tuple<decltype(args)...> t(args...);
  cout << get<3>(t) << endl;
}

template <auto... args>
struct ZZ
{
  std::tuple<decltype(args)...> t(args...);
};


int main()
{
   func<1,2,3,4>();
   ZZ<1,2,3> z;
}
```

While it works for `func` it does not work for the struct and results in the compile error (gcc trunk)

```
vs.cc:102:35: error: ‘args’ is not a type
  102 |   std::tuple<decltype(args)...> t(args...);
      |                                   ^~~~
```

Comment: `ZZ::t` attempts to declare a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, the [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) supports braces and equal-sign initializer, but not parentheses initializer. You can change the code to:

```
template <auto... args>
struct ZZ
{
  std::tuple<decltype(args)...> t{args...};
  //                             ^       ^
};
```

Or

```
template <auto... args>
struct ZZ
{
  std::tuple<decltype(args)...> t = std::tuple<decltype(args)...>(args...);
  //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

And with the help of [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (since C++17):

```
template <auto... args>
struct ZZ
{
  std::tuple<decltype(args)...> t = std::tuple(args...);
  //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Comment: Deduction guides make the decltype redundant, no?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes.